# discrete derivative of function

Tags: matlab, calculus, derivative

I have the following MWE that calculates the derivative of a function along the y-direction:

```
x=1:50;
y=x;

phi = sin((x-10)/10);



dyPhi = (4.0*(circshift(phi(:,:), [+0, +1]) - circshift(phi(:,:), [+0, -1])) + ...
         1.0*(circshift(phi(:,:), [+1, +1]) - circshift(phi(:,:), [-1, -1])) + ...
         1.0*(circshift(phi(:,:), [-1, +1]) - circshift(phi(:,:), [+1, -1])))/12.0;

figure(1)
imagesc(phi)
colorbar

figure(2)
imagesc(dyPhi)
colorbar
```

However, please take a look at the two plots: On the plot for *dyPhi*, it seems that the derivative has a wrong sign.

Why is that? If I swap the sign, then I get what I would expect.

Comment: Why exactly are you using `circshift`? There are more general ways of numerical differentiation or, if you are working only with `sin & cos`, you can simply "differentiate" by addition of `pi/2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the derivative using `f(x-1) - f(x+1)`, so the sign change is to be expected.

I would recommend [`gradient`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) for numerical differentiation.

[`plot(x,y)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot) is also more useful for visualizing functions, rather than `imagesc`.

---

With regards to your code, I'm a little confused by it.

`y` is a 1D vector, yet you seem to by trying to shift it in two dimensions with `circshift(phi(:,:), [-1, +1])`. The first shift dimension is irrelevant since `y` only has one row. This means that you are calculating the same thing three times, but scaling each result by `4.0`, `1.0`, and `1.0`.

As I mentioned, `circshift(phi,[0,1]) - circshift(phi,[0,-1])` is really calculating `f(x-1) - f(x+1)`. `circshift(phi,[0,1])` replaces each value `f(x)` with its past value `f(x-1)` because the shift is to the right. Likewise, a left shift with `circshift(phi,[0,-1])` replaces `f(x)` with `f(x+1)`.